# Complexity of SVD computation assuming knowing left singular vectors and singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, computational-complexity, svd

Suppose we know the left singular vectors $\mathbf{U}$ and singular values $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ for the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ with SVD decomposition $\mathbf{U}\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{V}^{\mathrm{H}}$, then what is the computational complexity of finding the right singular matrix $\mathbf{V}$? Is this computational complexity the same as the computational complexity of finding all three matrices $\mathbf{U}$, $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ and $\mathbf{V}$?

Comment: If all singular values of $A$ are non-zero, then $V$ can be computed with 
$$
V = [\Sigma^{-1}U^HA]^H = A^HU\Sigma^{-H},
$$
which means that the computational complexity is equal to that of matrix multiplication. If $A$ has zero singular values, then additional steps are necessary.